# fixing display of items in 2 columns layout dynamically

Tags: coldfusion, railo, lucee

I got the code, it displays items one after another:

```
<ul class="side-products-list padleft">
    <!-- Designers #1 Starts --> 
    <cfoutput query="lstdesigners">
      <cfset getProducts = Application.tools.getDesignerProducts(cw_designerID)>
      <li class="clearfix">
        <h5><a href="javascript:;">#reReplace(lcase(cw_designerName),"(^[a-z])","\U\1","ALL")# (#getProducts.total#)</a></h5>
        <cfif FileExists(Expandpath('corecontrol/designers/#image#'))>
          <img src="corecontrol/designers/#image#" alt="#cw_designerName#" class="img-responsive" />
          <cfelse>
          <img src="#request.imagespath#nomovieimage.jpg" alt="#cw_designerName#" class="img-responsive" />
        </cfif>
      </li>
    </cfoutput>
    <li>
      <h5><a href="javascript:;">All Designers</a></h5>
      <cfoutput><img src="#request.imagespath#icons-design.gif" width="122" height="114" alt="All Designers" class="img-responsive" /></cfoutput> </li>
    <!-- Designers #1 Ends -->
  </ul>
```

I want to show two column layout for this stuff, i am bit lost in this

any idea how can i use the mod operand with this ul li

Comment: Why dnt you use `lstdesigners.currentRow MOD {some number}` ?

Comment: i tried the above code, and i really don't know much about css.

Answer (score 1):

Does'nt look like much of an attempt Ramesh but I'll assume you are at the beginning and need rudimentary help here. The following is Un-debugged code (though Scott will probably notice if I add an eggregious error. :)

```
<cfset breakpoint = int(lstdesigners.recordcount / 2)>

<div id="thisiscolumn1">
  <cfloop query="lstdesigners">


   <cfif currentrow le breakpoint>
      ... do stuff for column 1 - your li code prob. goes here.
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
 </div>

<div id="thisiscolumn2">
  <cfloop query="lstDesigners">
    <cfif currentrow gt breakpoint>
      .... do stuff for column 2  .. li code.. etc.
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
</div>
```

This code is not optimal (it loops through the query twice and gives you the first half then the next half). Alternately you could use the "startrow / Maxrow" attributes of cfoutput or cfloop to acheive the same looping result.

Again this is just psuedo-code - an approach that will work. But the legwork will have to be up to you.